# Using touchesBegin/Moved/Ended to only affect movement of single uiimageview on screen despite multi-touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I have multiple images on screen that are draggable via touch, and currently I am using `touchesBegin:`, `touchesMoved:` and `touchesEnded:` to make these images movable.  My goal is to allow the user to be able to select **one** image on the screen via dragging, but noticed that if multiple fingers are used, multiple items could be dragged, and thus selected.  I was wondering if there is a way only allow one image to be dragged despite multiple fingers touch the screen.

As an alternative, I could certainly put up a condition and an alertview that informs the user only one image could be dragged when it detects multiple drag, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution in which I could impose some control on what the user could and could not do right from the touch level.

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting the a `multipleTouchEnabled` property of the corresponding Parent *view* instance to `NO`, in case if you have enabled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can add the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your main view and set the property `maximumNumberOfTouches` to 1. and handle the dragging of imageViews inside the selector method of UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess -  You can disable multiple touch on your view controller as well.